# Grant function execute to user in Postgres

Tags: permissions, postgresql

In documentation on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-grant.html theres a syntax to GRANT command.

```
GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { FUNCTION function_name ( [ [ argmode ] [ arg_name ] arg_type [, ...] ] ) [, ...]
         | ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

I trying to add execute permission to some function using this syntax but without success:

```
db=# GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION some_function TO some_user;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TO"
LINE 1: GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION some_function TO some_user...
```

Why there's so cohesion between documentation and reality? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

There was lack of "argument data types" in brackets after `function_name`. Function name and arguments data types we can check that by `\df` command.

```
 Schema |        Name        | Result data type          |Argument data types |  Type  
--------+--------------------+---------------------------+--------------------+--------
 public | some_function      | TABLE(some_results,....)  | numeric            | normal
```

Command should be:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION some_function(numeric) TO some_user;
```

But syntax has arguments in square brackets so they should be not necessary. But trying

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION some_function() TO some_user;
```

gives `function some_function() does not exist` error. So syntax to GRANT command should be:

```
GRANT { EXECUTE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON { FUNCTION function_name ( argmode arg_name arg_type [, ...] ] ) [, ...]
         | ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
    TO { [ GROUP ] role_name | PUBLIC } [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
The below example is how I granted execute privilege to efm user on pg_current_wal_lsn() system function.

postgres=# grant execute on function pg_current_wal_lsn() to efm;

GRANT

How to view the access granted on this function ?

postgres=# \x

Expanded display is on.

postgres=#

postgres=# \df+ pg_current_wal_lsn();

List of functions
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+---------------------------
Schema              | pg_catalog
Name                | pg_current_wal_lsn
Result data type    | pg_lsn
Argument data types |
Type                | func
Volatility          | volatile
Parallel            | safe
Owner               | kali
Security            | invoker
Access privileges   | =X/kali                   +
| kali=X/kali               +
| efm=X/kali
Language            | internal
Source code         | pg_current_wal_lsn
Description         | current wal write location